# Windows Explorer: How to open any file in my favourite editor?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Say [Kate](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NWMW7BB59HW) is my favorite editor. Then, using it from Powershell is a no-brainer:

```
kate path\to.file
```

How to do that in Windows Explorer? Four problems:

1. Windows Explorer has no idea what my favourite editor is when encountering yet another file extension. But everyone has a favourite editor; is there a place to set this once and for all?
2. *Right-click* -> *Open with*: Shows many alternatives, but not my favourite editor. Can I add it to this list?
3. *Right-click* -> *Open with* -> *Search for another app on this computer*: Navigating to the location of `kate.exe` and selecting it results in an error message: "No access to the file." How to debug this?
4. *Right-click* -> *Open with* -> *Search for an app in Windows Store*: I can find Kate and click "Start", but that opens without the file. I suppose it's not meant to work that way.

---

Or is there a more practical file manager for Windows?

Look to KDE: You can open any file in any program you have in the start menu, and if you don't find it there, any command in $PATH will do. No more locating executables! This was one of the first things I noticed about KDE that made me an addict 16 years ago (and makes me want Kate on Windows in the first place).

Comment: Did you install Kate from the Windows Store or from the nightly release, binary-factory.kde.org/view/Windows%2064-bit/job/… ? How did the install go? I just downloaded that Windows Kate file, extracted the zipped executable (two layers deep) to the Desktop, and Kate ran from there. I was then able to select a file in Explorer and choose to open with Kate.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I installed from Windows Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a more practical file manager for Windows?

[WinFile](https://github.com/microsoft/winfile) has a notion of an editor. In WinFile:

1. *Options* -> *Additional Preferences* -> *Editor Path*: Paste the full path to kate.exe or whatever.
2. Right-click on a file -> *Edit*
3. Et voila!

Answer (score 1):

Type `shell:sendto` in Run dialog (Winkey+R).

Right mouse drag `kate.exe` into the `sendto` folder and choose *Create Shortcut* when the menu pops up on release.

Now you can right click any file and choose *Send To* your editor. This user friendly way was introduced in Windows 95.

Comment: _Almost_ perfect! It opens the 8.3 name of the file, which truncates the extension. In the case of Kate, that interferes with its file type recognition. I'm thinking it must be possible to wrap this in a script that resolves short to long names.

Comment: I created a wrapper script (in powershell) that opens files in kate with their filenames expanded (`kate (Get-Item -LiteralPath $args).FullName`), but adding a shortcut to that in sendto apparently does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add other applications, e.g. Kate or Notepad++, to the *Open With...* list.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open *Explorer*.
- Right-click on a file of the type you want to open in Kate, e.g., with extension *.txt* or *.log*.
- Select *Open with...*.
- If your preferred application is not listed, select *Choose another app*.

[image: Open with... dlg]

Find the preferred executable and remember to check *Always use this app to open .txt files*.

You can also use Nirsoft's free [FileTypesMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to change how a file is opened, whether to edit, to play in a media player, or otherwise. If you're changing multiple extensions, or perhaps the whole MIME type, this is *far* more convenient then setting them one-at-a-time.

[image: Nirsoft's FileTypesMan]

Comment: That's what I tried when I got that error message.